# Is there a way to produce list of all classes/methods (without implementation) and save as a text file using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Normally c++ has a header file, but I just want java to generate list of all classes/methods and save it as text file. This is one of the requirement for my reports.

Thanks

Comment: One thing I will do will be try some regular expression scanning (grep or handwritten code). Something like this `(private|public|protected)(.*?)[(](.*?)[)]\s?[{]`

Answer (score 2):

Google [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) will generate a list of the classes in a specified package programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could [automatically generate Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689/javadoc-template-generator) then copy it to text, if that fits you.

If you only want descriptions, then just generate Javadoc for the visibility level you want from `Project -> Generate Javadoc` should be enough. It will give you the Javadoc in html format.

Also, writing Javadoc is a good habit; it could save you a lot of time for your next report.

Comment: I don't think I really want to bombard my existing code with javadoc, it will turn into a mess later on. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: @user385261: You don't have to write anything; just generate Javadoc for all the stuff (choose "private" when selecting "Create Javadoc for members with visibility"), then it'll produce the doc in a separate folder called "doc" (by default settings).

Answer (score 0):

If you have some time and appetite for creativity , you can create a small program , which will start from the root of your project , get the list of all file names and save to a text file.

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: I would like to, but I really need this fast

Answer (score 0):

Others already suggested javadoc, a similar approach would be doxygen. When you want just plain text, just run `javap` on all class files (you dont say which system you use, under unix you would do it with a `find basedir -name *.class -exec javap {} ;`).

That should create exactly what you want.

javap is a utility from the sdk (Class File Disassembler).

Default is to print only public, package and protected classes and member, but if you want more (also private) or less (just public), you can contril it with command line switches.